# Align widget inside shinydashboard box?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Is there a way of aligning a widget inside a `shinydashboard` box? For example, in the following app:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(box(
    title = "Test", width = 4, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary",
    dropdownButton(
      inputId = "mydropdown",
      label = "Controls",
      icon = icon("sliders"),
      status = "primary",
      circle = FALSE,
      numericInput("obs", "Observations:", 10, min = 1, max = 100)
    ),
    plotOutput('plot')
  ))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    hist(runif(input$obs))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

I would like to align the `dropdownButton` widget to the bottom right corner of the Test box. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put the `dropdownButton` after the plot and inside a div with a class `"pull-right"`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(box(
    title = "Test", width = 4, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary",
    plotOutput('plot'),
    div(class = "pull-right",
      dropdownButton(
        inputId = "mydropdown",
        label = "Controls",
        icon = icon("sliders"),
        status = "primary",
        circle = FALSE,
        numericInput("obs", "Observations:", 10, min = 1, max = 100)
      )
    )
  ))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    hist(runif(input$obs))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```